# jQuery / Javascript sum calculating as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, sum

I am calculating a total number of number inputs when they are changed, here are my inputs:

```html
<input type="number" class="qty mnm-quantity" step="3" min="0" max="9" name="mnm_quantity[197]" value="" title="Qty" size="4" placeholder="0" inputmode="numeric">
<input type="number" class="qty mnm-quantity" step="3" min="0" max="9" name="mnm_quantity[198]" value="" title="Qty" size="4" placeholder="0" inputmode="numeric">
<input type="number" class="qty mnm-quantity" step="3" min="0" max="9" name="mnm_quantity[199]" value="" title="Qty" size="4" placeholder="0" inputmode="numeric">
```

I then have the following script doing the sum:

```
var totalitems = 0;

$( ".mnm-quantity" ).each(function() {
        
    $(this).on('change', function() {
            
        totalitems += parseInt($(this).val());
            
        var quantity = $('.wc-pao-addon-select').find(":selected").data('label');
            
        if(totalitems >= quantity){
            $('.mnm-quantity').prop('readonly', true);
        }

        console.log(totalitems);
            
    });   
});
```

The sum calculates correctly when I increase the quantity of each field. In the console.log above, I get 3, 6 and then 9.

However if I increase the quantity of just one field, the console.log outputs 3 and then 9, and then the readonly function kicks in. By the looks of things its adding 3, and then the next step (of 3) which is 6, making the 9.

Can this be resolved in a way it works like increasing the 3 separate fields?

Comment: I think you want to spin over and sum them all up each time something changes, not just add on whatever individual value changed.

Comment: What is a "field" in this context? Can you please show the relevant HTML?

Comment: @WaisKamal a "field" is the number input's at the top of my question

Comment: Isolate your event handler from your data. The event is occurring independently of your `each`, so your `totalItems` is getting all out of whack.

Comment: You cannot change anything after you set them all to readonly. And the user can enter 9 in one field and can never change it again

Comment: @mplungjan thats the idea...however i do have a reset function, but didnt think that was relevant for the question

Comment: Use 3 dropdowns and remove the contents from the other for each value in each dropdown giving a total of the max you want

Answer (score 1):

You need a single change event listener and on every change, you need to recalculate the values

```
$(".mnm-quantity").on('change', function() {
var totalitems = 0;
$(".mnm-quantity").each(function(i,e) {
        totalitems += $.isNumeric(e.value) ? parseInt(e.value) : 0;
}); 
console.log(totalitems);
});
```

Comment: `const sum = $(".mnm-quantity").map((i,fld)=>+fld.value).get().reduce((a,b)=>a+b);`

Comment: It does not answer the question.